# Listbox inside pivot

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, uwp

I've got this code. I need to have access to the ScheduleList from my c# code. But it's inaccessible. I can get access to SchedulePivot only.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,50">
    <Pivot  x:Name="SchedulePivot" Margin="10,10,10,0" Title="Pivot" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox x:Name="ScheduleList" Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="Auto">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="52" Width="auto">
```

Searching on StackOverflow I have found this code:

```
private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
        {
            int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
            for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
                FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
                // Not a framework element or is null
                if (fe == null) return null;

                if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
                {
                    // Found the control so return
                    return child;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Not found it - search children
                    DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
                    if (nextLevel != null)
                        return nextLevel;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I use this line to get the child:

```
ListBox listCont = FindChildControl<ListBox>(this, "ScheduleList") as ListBox;
```

Also I tried doing like this:

```
ListBox listCont = FindChildControl<ListBox>(SchedulePivot, "ScheduleList") as ListBox;
```

than I do this:

```
listCont.Items.Add(items);
```

And get the exeption as listCont=null. What's wrong I'm doing?

Comment: When (and from where) are you calling the FindChildControl?

Comment: As the xaml code is located inside the MainPage.xaml, I've declared this method inside MainPage.xaml.cs and I'm calling it from void,which runs, when button is clicked

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your code, both of the following code work well in my side and I can get the correct result:

```
ListBox listCont = FindChildControl<ListBox>(this, "ScheduleList") as ListBox;
ListBox listCont = FindChildControl<ListBox>(SchedulePivot, "ScheduleList") as ListBox;
```

If we want to access the control by using the VisualTreeHelper, we should make sure that we have not called the above code inside the constructor of the MainPage, or we will get the null result as below. Because the control does not been initialized completely:
[image]

In order to get the correct result, we need to call the above code inside the [MainPage.Loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded) event or Button click event to make sure that control has been initialized completely, after that it should work fine.

The following is my sample, please try to refer to:

In the MainPage.xaml:

```
<Pivot x:Name="SchedulePivot" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotTestlist}" Margin="10,10,10,0" Title="Pivot" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding header}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox x:Name="ScheduleList" Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxTestlist}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="52" Width="auto">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>

    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button"></Button>
```

In the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 public class ListBoxTest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class PivotTest
{
    public List<ListBoxTest> ListBoxTestlist { get; set; }
    public string header { get; set; }
}
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<PivotTest> PivotTestlist { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        PivotTestlist = new List<PivotTest>();
        PivotTest PivotTest1 = new PivotTest();
        PivotTest1.ListBoxTestlist = new List<ListBoxTest>();
        PivotTest1.ListBoxTestlist.Add(new ListBoxTest() { name = "name1", id = "id1" });
        PivotTest1.ListBoxTestlist.Add(new ListBoxTest() { name = "name2", id = "id2" });
        PivotTest1.header = "header1";
        PivotTestlist.Add(PivotTest1);
        PivotTest PivotTest2 = new PivotTest();
        PivotTest2.ListBoxTestlist = new List<ListBoxTest>();
        PivotTest2.ListBoxTestlist.Add(new ListBoxTest() { name = "name11", id = "id11" });
        PivotTest2.ListBoxTestlist.Add(new ListBoxTest() { name = "name22", id = "id22" });
        PivotTest2.header = "header2";
        PivotTestlist.Add(PivotTest2);
        this.DataContext = this;

    }
    private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
    {
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            // Not a framework element or is null
            if (fe == null) return null;

            if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
            {
                // Found the control so return
                return child;
            }
            else
            {
                // Not found it - search children
                DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
                if (nextLevel != null)
                    return nextLevel;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listCont = FindChildControl<ListBox>(SchedulePivot, "ScheduleList") as ListBox;
        int count = listCont.Items.Count;
    }
}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: I've checked and it doesn't work. May be we can have contact via skype or e-mail, so you will be able to help me

Comment: Could you please share you project with the .cs code in the GitHub or Onedrive? In this way I can test your project to see where is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Pivot in a storyboard and use the x:Key instead of x:Name.

e.g.

`<StoryBoard>
<Pivot x:key="nameIt"/>
</StoryBoard>
private void AccesPivot () 
{ //now you can acces your pivot
}`

Comment: I need to have access to listbox, not to pivot

Comment: Sorry,I haven't read this carefully. You can do basically the same thing as with the pivot,declare the listbox inside a storyboard asign an x:key to it and use it in the code behind

Comment: story board is not supported in windows universal apps